# XCode 4 - Adding system icons to Toolbar

Tags: xcode, toolbar

I am creating a toolbar for a Mac application in Xcode 4. I added some buttons, and specified image icons (to represent Actions, etc, etc.) The image library seems to be small: I see the "NSActionTemplate" image, and other common ones, but I don't see other icons Apple is using - like the "Arrange" icon from Finder, the New Folder Icon, etc. Am I out of luck? Is Apple expecting you to create those yourself? Or, is there an image library I am supposed to enable to see more? thanks,

Answer (score 0):

See "System-Provided Icons" at OS X Human Interface Guidelines:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/SystemProvidedIcons/SystemProvidedIcons.html